# Download CSV from Google Fusion API with particular name and explicit .csv file extension

Tags: csv, google-fusion-tables

I have been successfully requesting a csv file from the Google Fusion API, however, the downloaded file is named "query" and does not have an explicit file extension of .csv. Here is my API request (with the table ID and key taken out for obvious reasons).

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%<TABLE_ID>%20order%20by%20timeFinished%20desc%20limit%20100&key=<KEY>&alt=csv
```

Is there a way I can specify both an explicit file extension of .csv and name the file that will be downloaded something other than 'query'?